# Redis - `CONFIG REWRITE failed: Permission denied`

Tags: permissions, centos7, service, redis

I am trying to install and configure a `redis` service on `centos7`.

`redis` tries to rewrite its configuration file from time to time with no success, so it throws the following error:

```
CONFIG REWRITE failed: Permission denied
```

the file exists in `/etc/redis.conf`, and it's permissions are:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 redis redis 46765 Jun 13 06:20 /etc/redis.conf
```

I even tried to change the permission to `chmod 777 /etc/redis.conf`, and that did not fix the issue.

`redis` runs under the user `redis`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most certainly you have issues with SElinux. Either disable it (which I don't recommend) with `setenforce 0` for a temp disable, or change the permissive/disabled mode in `/etc/selinux/config` for a permanent "solution".

What you should do is configure SElinux to allow redis to work - I suggest you start from here: [Unable to start Redis under SELinux](https://serverfault.com/questions/816052/unable-to-start-redis-under-selinux)

Comment: This worked! could you also point me to a detail explanation of why this is preventing the redis service from modifying its files? I would like to see if there's a better way than disabling this security feature completely

Comment: SElinux is kernel module which provides additional security layers. Files and directories get a `context`, there are also flags to configure which program can access the network to "talk" to another program. Check https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux for more information. As I said my answer - I suggest you try to configure `redis` to work with selinux, rather than disabling it. The link in my answer contains instructions on how to do that.